# Bash read N lines from file starting from line Z

Tags: bash, head

I have text file:

```
34
3467uy
56ytyyu
And so on
```

I want to read from this file N lines starting from line Z. I know how to read first N lines with (head -n N) or last with tail. I know now how to read from line Z to the end of the file with tail. But I can't find how to read specific amount starting from specific line.
Help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be accomplished using `sed`.  For example, to emit lines 10 through 20 in a file:

```
sed -n '10,+10p' a_file
```

Comment: Thank you! This also help! But why do I get different results?

Comment: @GogaBenton results are different because, this is printing between line 10 and 20, not 20 lines from line 10.

Comment: Looks like sed eats \n or dislike them somehow

Answer (score 1):

Pipe `tail`'s output to `head`:

```
tail -n +Z file | head -n N
```

For example:

```
$ seq 100 | tail -n +15 | head -n 5
15
16
17
18
19
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` : Below example would print from line 3 to line 5(3+2 lines).set the `start_line` and `buffer` variables to print the line starting from `start_line` plus `buffer` more lines.

```
awk -vstart_line=3 -vbuffer=2 'NR>=start_line && NR<=start_line+buffer' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
seq 1 10 | sed '2,+3!d'
```

Output:

```
2
3
4
5
```

From `man sed`:

> `addr1,+N`:  Will match addr1 and the N lines following addr1.

Comment: A refinement: `sed -n '2,+3 p; 6q'` the `6q` will keep it from bothering to read through the rest of the possibly large file before exiting. It does require preparatory math, though...